# POSTGIS error in getting proper intersected output (St_intersect, st_buffer)

Tags: postgis, st-intersects

I need to get gid, area and geometry  of table1  which are  intersecting with 
 200 buffer of table2. I tried to structure the query. Please refer below:

```
create table SMI_1 as 
SELECT ST_Buffer(geom, 200) from table2;

create table SAH_2 as 
SELECT a.gid,a.shape_area, a.geom 
FROM table1 a 
INNER JOIN SMI_1 b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.st_buffer);
```

With this I am not getting desired output. It is not clipping the features of table1  with the shape of the table2.

Comment: Your query doesn't ask for the clipped pieces, just the overlapping ones.  Break out some documentation and review the difference between `ST_Intersects` and `ST_Intersection`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I used ST_Intersection to get the result

Answer (score 1):

This query will return geometries from SAH_2 which are intersecting with geometries from SMI_1. If you need a geometry of this intersection you need to use ST_Intersection function:

```
create table SAH_2 as (
  WITH SMI_1 as ( 
    SELECT ST_Buffer(geom, 200) from table2)
  SELECT a.gid,a.shape_area, ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.st_buffer) as geom
  FROM table1 a 
  INNER JOIN SMI_1 b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.st_buffer));
```